# What is the Aegir make_working_copy SCM option mean?

Tags: version-control, aegir, drush

If one creates a platform and chooses to preserve the working copy, does this initiate a .git clone that the aegir user from CLI, could update and merge branches to?

> Create a new platform:
>
> > Drush make option:
> >
> > > - Normal - Discards SCM files
> > > - Working copy - preserves SCM files

Where is the working copy directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Drush make option' field in the Aegir user interface (when creating a new platform based on a makefile) simply determines whether or not the `--working-copy` option is passed to Drush make.

The `--working-copy` option for Drush make "preserves VCS directories, like .git, for projects downloaded using such methods." (source: [Drush.org](http://drush.ws/#make))

Passing the `--working-copy` option leaves the .git directories intact (as if you had done a manual `git clone`) and hence allows you to pull in updates, etc.
However, this is not the [recommended way](http://community.aegirproject.org/faq#How_do_I_update_a_site-s_or_platform-s_modules_using_Aegir) of updating modules in Aegir, so the 'Normal - Discards SCM files' option is preferred.

The [aegir_make_working_copy](https://github.com/computerminds/aegir_make_working_copy) module provided this functionality for Aegir 1.x, before it was merged into Aegir core 2.x.

Comment: great so if I "put" the theme in the profile, the libraries and even the modules (why not?*rhetoric question) the developers with the right version control keys could "update css files and work on Features" right from their shell (that's almost all you need to manage a hosted site and invent three other jobs!) and pull their own branch, anytime, at wish. thank you. that was the piece missing.